# Changing datatype for multiple Pandas DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 19 columns (q1 to q19) in a DataFrame 'users' I want to convert from float to int. Instead of manually typing it out is there a way to automate the process?

Code I have so far is:

```
users.q1 = users.q1.astype(int)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention there are other columns in the dataframe I want to keep as other datatypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
df.loc[:, 'q1':'q19'] = df.loc[:, 'q1':'q19'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a list of the columns that you want to alter:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [2, 3, 8], 'C':[5, 9, 12]})

df1[['A', 'B']] = df1[['A', 'B']].astype('float')
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    A    B   C
0  1.0  2.0   5
1  2.0  3.0   9
2  3.0  8.0  12
```

Instead of altering line for line, we can simplify to one line for all of the columns that need to be changed.

Comment: One thing, `float` in the `astype` does not need to be a string

Comment: @U8-Forward I am fairly certain that in numpy it does have to be a string, which is why I do so in Pandas. That may not be accurate, but I vaguely remember it having to be a string a few years ago, and I assumed it was the same in pandas. I could be wrong.

Comment: Ok but at least i know now that you can just do `.astype(float)`

Comment: @U8-Forward Thanks. I will test if you can do that in numpy. I recall getting a syntax error in Numpy when I attempted to pass float in the "dtype" argument a few years ago. So I have figured it was the same in Pandas ever since. Thanks for the knowledge. I just thought that you had to pass a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in users.columns:
    if <condition>:
        users[i] = users[i].astype(int)
```